# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "darse pisto"?

Tags: etimología, modismos

El Diccionario de la lengua define [**pisto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TDdbwD7) como

> 1. m. Fritada de pimientos, tomates, huevo, cebolla o de otros alimentos, picados y revueltos.
> 2. m. Jugo o sustancia que se obtiene de la carne de ave, y se da caliente al enfermo que solo puede tragar líquidos.
> 3. m. Mezcla confusa de diversas cosas en un discurso o en un escrito.
> 4. m. El Salv., Guat., Hond. y Nic. dinero.

y la expresión **darse pisto** como

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Darse importancia.

La aparición más antigua que he encontrado en el CORDE es de 1884 (Pérez Galdós: *La de Bringas*):

> ¡Soplaollas, fantasmonas! Y luego venían aquí **dándose un pisto**... "Grandísimas... -les digo para mí-, yo no engaño a nadie; yo vivo de mi trabajo. Pero vosotras engañáis a medio mundo y queréis hacer vestidos de seda con el pan del pobre. Y oígalas usted echar humo por aquellas bocas, criticando y despreciando a otras pobres.

En el NTLLE no aparece hasta 1895, en el diccionario de Zerolo:

> *Darse pisto.* fr. fig. y fam. Presumir.

Pero ¿de dónde viene la expresión?

Comment: Yo siempre había oído "darse **el** pisto" o "tirarse **el** pisto" con artículo, del origen de la expresión no tengo ni idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque el pisto es (mejor dicho *era*) un plato muy complicado de hacer.

> También empleado como "tirarse el pisto", utilizamos este giro al querer indicar que alguien se está dando importancia o fanfarroneando al vanagloriarse de sus mérito
>
> La historia de esta expresión se centra en la elaboración del pisto, pero no en la actual [...]  sino en su anterior confección, basada en el empleo de diferentes carnes machacadas y sus jugos, de costosa preparación y sólo al alcance de los más pudientes. **Tal era el trabajo y el coste de dicho plato, que "darse el pisto" comenzó a relacionarse con el atribuirse un mérito y por lo tanto concederse un "premio" por él**, y tal cual, dicha expresión ha llegado hasta nuestros días.
>
> fuente: [este blog](http://origenlenguaje.blogspot.com/2013/05/origen-de-la-expresion-darse-el-pisto.html)

La [entrada de "pisto" en la wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisto_manchego) confirma que

> "pisto" [se asocia] etimológicamente a *pistare* que significa **jugo de carne** de ave (caldo de gallina), o del latín *pistus* ("machacado") y así era en **la cocina española en el siglo XVII**.